# Heroku Deployment with Django: Webpack Bundle returns content of index.html instead of actual bundle

Tags: django, heroku, webpack, production

The application runs fine in development, but once in production the generated webpack bundle file is serving the contents of index.html and not all the bundled modules and dependencies.

Whenever I check the bundle file on the server, everything seems alright, but the same path is served differently on the client.

webpack.config.js

```
//require our dependencies
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
    //the base directory (absolute path) for resolving the entry option
    context: __dirname,
    //the entry point we created earlier. Note that './' means 
    //your current directory. You don't have to specify the extension  now,
    //because you will specify extensions later in the `resolve` section
  entry: [
      './assets/js/index'
  ],    
  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'), 
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
  },

    plugins: [
        //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // don't reload if there is an error
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), 
        //makes jQuery available in every module
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery' 
        })
    ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      // we pass the output from babel loader to react-hot loader
      { 
        test: [/\.js$/, /\.es6$/, /\.jsx?$/],
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loaders: ['babel'], 
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  },

    resolve: {
        //tells webpack where to look for modules
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        //extensions that should be used to resolve modules
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'] 
    }   
}
```

Served Content:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<title></title>-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="container"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/bundles/main-210eb139915d8d6abedf.js" ></script>
  </body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as Django?

Comment: Application was constructed using the Django framework. I'm unsure as to whether it's a Django misconfiguration that's redirecting the client to the index page.